# Migrate Entity Parent in CoreData

Tags: database, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, parent

I have a CoreDatabase model that is already used in the App Store, so I need to devise a way to migrate the model without losing the previous data.  I have an entity that currently does not have a parent object, but I need to set its parent entity in the new model.  However, when I try to do this, I get a crash that says that CoreData was unable to migrate the database model.

If anyone could provide an insight into how I would accomplish this, I'd really appreciate it!

EDIT: I get an Cannot migrate store in-place error with the underlying error of "SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: _T_ZCONTACT', reason=Failed to execute migration statements".  The "Contact" is the name of the entity I need to change the parent for.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a new entity having the same attributes as the old entity, set the new one's parent, then migrate the old entity to new one;
second, change all of invoke to the new entity.